# Signout from another activity in Google plus integration is not work

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, google-plus

I am following this [**tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) it is working fine but in my app i have multiple activity like **SplashActivity -->MainActivity-->MyNewMainActivity**

MyNewMainActivtiy.java contains 3 fragment like **SearchFragment--> NearbyFragment--> ProfileFragment**

I have completing login successfully and get the profile information and set the name and picture in **profileFragment** i have set a logout button from where i want to logout from google plus and back to LoginActivity
and when i click on googleplus login button again it shows error

```
 07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.rstm.doctorrx.LoginActivity.resolveSignInError(LoginActivity.java:279)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.rstm.doctorrx.LoginActivity.signInWithGplus(LoginActivity.java:345)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.rstm.doctorrx.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:114)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17343)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-02 11:24:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.rstm.doctorrx;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.doctorrx.integration.FacebookService;
import com.doctorrx.integration.FacebookService.FacebookFriendListRequester;
import com.doctorrx.integration.UserContext;
import com.doctorrx.integration.Utils;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

public class LoginActivity  extends Activity implements OnClickListener , FacebookFriendListRequester,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    public static int socialLogin;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    ImageButton cross_btn;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Button login_btn, signup_btn,google_btn,facbook_login_btn;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    // Logcat tag
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

        // Google client to interact with Google API
        private static  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        cross_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cross_btn);
        login_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        signup_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
        google_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.google_login_btn);
        facbook_login_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.facbook_login_btn);
        initialiseGoogleclient();
        facbook_login_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        google_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        signup_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        cross_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
//      try {
//          PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
//                  "com.rstm.doctorrx", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
//          for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
//              MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
//              md.update(signature.toByteArray());
//              Log.e("MY KEY HASH:",
//                      Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
//          }
//      } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
//
//      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.facbook_login_btn:
            socialLogin=404;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            loadMyFriendList();
            break;
        case R.id.cross_btn:
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.login_btn:
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),LoginDetailActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
            break;
        case R.id.register_btn:
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),SignupActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
            break;
        case R.id.google_login_btn:
            socialLogin=401;
            initialiseGoogleclient();
            signInWithGplus();
            break;

        }
    }

    private void initialiseGoogleclient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }
    private void loadMyFriendList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (Utils.haveNetworkConnection(this)) {
            dialog.setMessage("Verifying credentials...");
            dialog.show();
            FacebookService.instance().setContext(getApplicationContext());
            if (!Utils.isAuthenticated()) {

                FacebookService.instance().fetchFacebookProfile(this);
            } else {
                UserContext.authorized = true;
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MyNewMainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();

            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onListFetched(ArrayList<JSONObject> onLinefriends,
            ArrayList<JSONObject> idleLinefriends,
            ArrayList<JSONObject> offLinefriends) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //dialog.dismiss();

    }
    @Override
    public void onFbError() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    public void onFacebookProfileRetreived(boolean isSuccess) {
        // override this method
        if (isSuccess) {

            startActivity(new Intent(this,MyNewMainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some Error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(socialLogin==404){
        if (!UserContext.authorized) {
            FacebookService.instance().authorizeCallback(requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);
            UserContext.authorized = true;
            //dialog.dismiss();

        }
        }
        if(socialLogin==401)
        {
                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) 
                {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        mSignInClicked = false;
                    }

                    mIntentInProgress = false;

                    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
        }

    }
//  public void onStart() {
//      super.onStart();
//      if (!Utils.haveNetworkConnection(this)) {
//          showNoConnectionDialog();
//      }
//  }

    private void showNoConnectionDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Error in Network Connection!").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        finish();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.show();
    }
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;
        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle paramBundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSignInClicked = false;

    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();
    if(socialLogin==401){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MyNewMainActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    finish();}
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int paramInt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
 * */



/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {

    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);


            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
//          personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
//                  personPhotoUrl.length() - 2);
            if(mPrefs == null){
                mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("login",401);
            editor.putString("Guser_name", personName);
            editor.putString("Guserpic_url", personPhotoUrl);
            editor.commit();
            UserContext.MyPicUrl=personPhotoUrl;
            UserContext.MyDisplayName=personName;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-out from google
 * */
public static void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
/**
 * Revoking access from google
 * */
public   void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }

                });
    }
}



}
```

**profileFragment**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    Button logout_btn;
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, container, false);
         TextView name =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_name);
         ImageView myimage=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_pic);
         logout_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);

         logout_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();

                // for Normal Login
                 if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -404)==201)
                 {
                     editor.putString("normal_login_username", "");
                     editor.putInt("normallogin", -201);
                 }
                 // for Gmail
                 if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -404)==401)
                 {
                     LoginActivity.signOutFromGplus();
                     LoginActivity.socialLogin=-10;
                     editor.putInt("login", -401);
                 }
                 // for Facebook
                 if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -404)==404)
                 {
                     new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                     editor.putInt("login", -404);

                 }
                editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish(); 

            }
        });
         if(mPrefs == null){
                mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }

         if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -401)==401){
               name.setText(mPrefs.getString("Guser_name", "Dummy User"));
               Utils.loadImageFromUrl(myimage, mPrefs.getString("Guserpic_url", "nothing found"));
            }
         if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -404)==404)
         {
             name.setText(mPrefs.getString("display_name", "Dummy User"));
             Utils.loadImageFromUrl(myimage, mPrefs.getString("profile_url", "nothing found"));
            }

         if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -404)==201)
         {
             name.setText(mPrefs.getString("normal_login_username", "Dummy User"));
            }
         return rootView;
     }    


        @Override
        public void onStart() {     
            super.onStart();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 try {
                        FacebookService.instance().signout();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return null;
            }

        }



}
```

my problem is how to logout form another fragmnet/activity from googleplus.
Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to handle this problem,

- Initialize GooglePlusClient making global throughout the application using singleton class/initializing it in application class.
- Or you have to initialize the gplusclient in all activity(For that, write an abstract/base activity class with all gplus functionalities like sigin,signout and extend this base class in all activity where you want to handle gplus functions.

One more suggestion: Handle GplusClient object (like logout/login )in activity instead of fragment.Logic to communitcate between fragments/activity is as follow

- Define an interface in your fragment
- Implement that interface in activity
- Communicate through this interface (for eg: if you have button in fragment, on button click, call the interface function, which is implemented by activity, and handle it in activity). [Google site will help you (with examples)](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

For example(BaseActivity example)

```
public class GplusBaseActivity extends Activity implements PlusClientFragment.OnSignedInListener {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_FRAGMENT = 1550;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_PICK = 1551;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_API = 1552;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private PlusClientFragment mGPlusSignInFragment;
    protected PlusClient mPlusClient;
    protected Context mContext;
    protected LoginHelper.GplusLoginCallback mOnGplusLoginCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        mGPlusSignInFragment =
                PlusClientFragment.getPlusClientFragment(this, MomentUtil.ACTIONS);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupActionBar(ActionBar actionBar) {

    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return this;
    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    public void gplusLogin(LoginHelper.GplusLoginCallback gplusLoginCallback) {
        mOnGplusLoginCallback = gplusLoginCallback;
        mGPlusSignInFragment.signIn(REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignedIn(PlusClient plusClient) {
        mPlusClient = plusClient;
        Person currentPerson = plusClient.getCurrentPerson();
        // After signin code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_FRAGMENT) {
            L.d("onActivityResult: from G+,requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode:" + resultCode);
            mGPlusSignInFragment.handleOnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } 
    }

    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            //L.d("Google Play services is available.");
            return true;
        } else {

            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    resultCode, this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            if (errorDialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "Locations Updates");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void showSelectAccountsUI() {
        try {
            Intent intent = AccountPicker
                    .newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                            new String[]{"com.google"}, true, null, null,
                            null, null);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    REQUEST_CODE_PLUS_CLIENT_PICK);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            L.wrong(mContext);
            servicesConnected();
        }
    }


    private static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private Dialog mDialog;

        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    public void gplusLogout() {
        if (mPlusClient != null) {
            L.d("Loggin out G+");
            plusSignOut(mPlusClient);
        }
    }

    private void plusSignOut(PlusClient plusClient) {
        if (plusClient.isConnected()) {
            plusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
            plusClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        gplusLogout();
    }

}
```

Example for your Main activity with fragments:

Suppose you have LogoutFragment where you want to logout from g+

```
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {
    LogoutFragmentListener mLogoutFragmentListener;
    public interface LogoutFragmentListener{
        public void onLogoutBtnClick();
    }

    Button mLogoutButton; // this is your sign-out btn 

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            mLogoutFragmentListener=(LogoutFragmentListener)activity;
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Parent activity should implement LogoutFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLogoutFragmentListener.onLogoutBtnClick();
            }
        });
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

and your main activity as

```
public class MainActivity extends GplusBaseActivity implements LogoutFragment.LogoutFragmentListener {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onLogoutBtnClick(){
        gplusLogout(); // method from super class
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please provide me sample code apart from link you have given

Comment: added an base activity example which I used to do. LoginActivity can extend GplusBaseActivity, and call appropriate method.

Comment: can you explain some more how to maintain googleApiClient object in application application using singleton class/initializing it in application class.am using google plus login example using from android hive after logeedin am navigate to another activity.i need to logout from that activity android please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by implementing  **ConnectionCallbacks and  OnConnectionFailedListener** interface in my **MyNewMainActivity.java** which host all my fragments(Search,Nearby and Profile)and call signout function from **ProfileFragment** like this

```
((MyNewMainActivity)getActivity()).signOutFromGplus();
```